# using AES_DECRYPT to get data

Tags: php, mysql, aes

I am trying to retrieve data from a table from some old legacy work, the Email field all have '[BLOB - 32 B]' in the fields therefore has been encrypted - can anyone explain how I use the AES_DECRYPT to collect the actual email address from this table?

I have the AES_PASSWORD in var stored already within one of the common functions.

Comment: Sorry, I am indeed using PHP/MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `$key = AES_PASSWORD` (Your key for the data)

Your SQL would be

`$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tblemail (email) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('$email','$key'))";`

`$sqlget = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(email,'$key') from tblemail;";`

Comment: Do you want quotes around `$key` in the insert statement also?